# find files that start with the same set of charecters Linux

Tags: regex

In an attempt to backup their website a client of mine ended up duplicating every file and directory in my php apps file system.  Each file begins: C:\Users\Nick\Desktop... then the path to the file within my file system.

I tried writing a regular expression to find every file that begins with that string but I'm having trouble, I've not used regular expressions very often and I find them very confusing.  This would be a good opportunity to learn a bit more about them, but I'm swamped and this problem was completely unexpected.  Would someone share their expertise?

Thanks

Comment: If you're after just removing all copies within the users\nick\desktop directory, surely you could just itterate through the files in your website, and test if it exists in the \users\nick\desktop structure by appending the file+path from your apps folders, and delete it. 

In fact, I missed why you would want to use regexpr for this.but I guess

"^C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\(.*)" would be a suitable regexpr to test

Comment: The files are interspersed throughout the directory structure.  So, directory X would have all of the files I had made, along with additional copies made by the client.  If directory Y was nested in directory X then along with all of his copies would be an additional copy of directory Y,  his duplicate files would also be in my copy of directory Y.  I'm using codeigniter, and so there are a lot of directories and files in there.  I'm not sure how the client even did it.  But it's a mess.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If it just begins with the same string every, time there's no need for a regular expression - just use the normal string search of your platform. The regular expression for constant values is just the constant value, in your case:

```
^C:\\Users\\Nick\\Desktop\\
```

`^` matches only the start of the input (file name), and backslashes need to be escaped.